# Appending to bash_profile (the specifics)

Tags: unix, path, rbenv, bash

Apparently if I want to initialize rbenv automatically (in order to install gems), I need to append

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

to my bash_profile. However, I have no idea what I am doing with Unix and when I open up bash_profile in TextEditor I get this:

```
export PATH="/Users/student/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

I have tried to put it in multiple places, and it doesn't work. Where do I put it?

P.S. I know that if I knew a little more, I could derive the answer from another post, but I know nothing about this and cannot distinguish one thing in the PATH from another. (Please don't mark as duplicate).

UPDATE: I tried the suggestion by Robert I., so that now the profile reads:

I tried that so now the profile reads:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 4.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/student/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

I am trying to install jekyll and bundler, and I still get the same Gem:FilePermissionsError. Did I do it wrong, or could there be some other error?

Answer (score 0):

if you are editing yout ~/.bash_profile
simple append
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
at the bottom of the file then either use source ~/.bash_profile or reload your connection.

Comment: Please see above^^

Comment: try putting it at the end of the line in your ~/.bashrc and then run source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Can you run these commands on the shell directly? eval "$(rbenv init -)";   sudo gem install jekyll

Comment: Sorry I have been away from this. I followed your last suggestion, and: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/jekyll